# Redshift regular expression for domain extraction

Tags: regex, amazon-redshift, regexp-substr

I'm trying to form a regular expression for `REGEXP_SUBSTR (Redshift)` which will extract the sub-domain & domain part from any given URL.

I tried many suggestions from stackoverflow: regular-expression-extract-subdomain-domain, getting-parts-of-a-url-regex, how-to-get-domain-name-from-url and etc. Some of them work on regex validator but don’t work on Redshift.

*A regular expression should handle URLs with and without http/https prefix.*

**Is there any other way of extracting sub-domain & domain from any given URL using a regular expression?**

Comment: Check this UDF blog post: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/user-defined-functions-for-amazon-redshift/

Answer (score 6):

After a **ton** of experimentation, this is what I use:

```
REPLACE(REGEXP_SUBSTR(url,'//[^/\\\,=@\\+]+\\.[^/:;,\\\\\(\\)]+'),'//','')
```

Need to match the double slash and then remove it with `REPLACE` because of the quite basic regex supported by Redshift.

FWIW, you'll notice that this is *very* different from the regex provided by Jeff Barr in the [Redshift UDF's intro](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/user-defined-functions-for-amazon-redshift/) - that regex produces **nothing** for me.