# How is the regex for extracting domain from URL constructed

Tags: regex, amazon-redshift, regexp-substr

I saw an SO answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36834716/redshift-regular-expression-for-domain-extraction) which has the SQL to extract domain from a URL in Redshift. I am very new to Regex. Is it possible to understand the answer step by step?

```
REPLACE(REGEXP_SUBSTR(url,'//[^/\\\,=@\\+]+\\.[^/:;,\\\\\(\\)]+'),'//','')
```

All I have come to understand so far is ^ means that to match the beginning of a string and anything between square brackets [] is a character set, but I want to understand this regex in and out.

Answer (score 0):

Certainly! Let's break down the regular expression step by step:

```
REGEXP_SUBSTR(url,'//[^/\\\,=@\\+]+\\.[^/:;,\\\\\(\\)]+')
```

This part of the regular expression is used to extract a portion of the url string. It searches for a pattern starting with // followed by one or more characters that are not `/, \, ,, =, @, +, :, ;, (, ),` or a dot (.). The `[^...]` construct represents a negated character class, meaning any character that is not within the square brackets.

For example, given the input https://www.example.com/path, this expression would match //www.example.com.

```
 REPLACE(matchedString, '//', '')
```

This part of the regular expression is used to replace the // substring in the matchedString (output of the previous step) with an empty string. It effectively removes the // from the extracted portion of the URL.

Continuing with the previous example, the output would be [www.example.com](http://www.example.com), as the // is replaced with an empty string.

Therefore, when this regular expression is applied to a URL, it extracts the domain name (excluding any protocol or path) and removes any leading // if present.

Comment: Just to confirm I have understood the break down correctly, the first [^..] matches the pattern till the first dot is found. So, https://www.example.com/path would fetch //www.    How is that using just one dot its able to fetch the entire pattern with multiple dots (//www.example.com)

Comment: did you use any generative AI at all in the writing of this answer?